# How can I grab the title of a YouTube video using javascript with no YouTube API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I am making a chrome extension and I need to grab the title of youtube videos. I don't want to use the youtube api.

[Here is the code in my content script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGoYC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by doing `var videotitle = document.title.split(" - YouTube")[0];`

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the tab title in the background.js, it will return the youtube video title

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (activeInfo) {
chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function (tab) {
    console.log("Title: " + tab.title);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this line of code in the F12 developer tools:

> ytInitialPlayerResponse.videoDetails.title

The same line of code should work on your extension as well.